# Custom bucketing structure on the basis of date is not working properly

Tags: content-editor, buckets

Recently I was creating a custom action for creating custom bucket rules, and I followed the instructions from [this](https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/04/how-to-create-custom-item-bucket-rules-in-sitecore-cms/) link. Everything went well but when I sync the bucketed folder, then on the basis of the date field it should create the folder structure but, the structure it is creating is one day before the provided date, for example if I pass the date `8/4/2017` the folder structure it is creating is based on date `8/3/2017`

I check the date field, when I checked the raw values, I am getting 1 day before.

Comment: It looks your server is in a different culture, did you try by adding you current culture as CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
ruleContext.ResolvedPath = date.ToString(format, culture); please try this.

Comment: I debuged the code and i am using this culture only

Comment: in your debug what value you are getting in ResolvedPath?

Comment: When you select a date on any date field. Is the raw value ok or not? If not, this is a timezone issue. Do you have anything set on  ServerTimeZone setting?

Comment: earlier there was no servertimezone , so i set that to IST then it is working now

Answer (score 1):

Set the setting `<setting name="ServerTimeZone" value="" />` to match the desired timezone.

> The Server Time Zone setting in the web.config file specifies the server time zone that is used by the server to convert UTC time to local time

Source: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/settings-supporting-utc-implementation.html